# Golf the Subset-Sum Problem

Tags: code-golf, math

## Task

Given a list of space-delimited integers as input, output all unique non-empty subsets of these numbers that each subset sums to 0.

---

### Test Case

Input:  `8 −7 5 −3 −2`
Output: `-3 -2 5`

---

### Winning Criterion

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Do we have to worry about uniqueness if the input contains non-unique numbers?  In other words, how many results do I have to print for the input `3 3 -3 -3`?

Comment: @Keith.  By convention, sets consist of distinct elements that appear at most once.  Multisets can have elements that appear more than once. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Comment: @DavidCarraher, OP mixes terminology by talking about subsets of lists.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks. Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 41 characters

```
~][[]]\{`{1$+$}+%}%;(;.&{{+}*!},{" "*}%n*
```

If you do not care about the specific output format you can shorten the code to 33 characters.

```
~][[]]\{`{1$+$}+%}%;(;.&{{+}*!},`
```

Example (see [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyI4IC03IDUgLTMgLTIgNCIKCn5dW1tdXVx7YHsxJCskfSslfSU7KDsuJnt7K30qIX0seyIgIip9JW4qCgpwcmludA%3D%3D)):

```
> 8 -7 5 -3 -2 4
-3 -2 5
-7 -2 4 5
-7 -3 -2 4 8
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 9 characters

```
{⊇.+0∧}ᵘb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@1/9qKtdT9vgUcfy2odbZyT9/x9toRNvrmOqE2@sE2@kYxL7PwoA)

```
{⊇.+0∧}ᵘb
 ⊇           subset
   +0        that sums to 0
  .  ∧       output the subset
{     }ᵘ     take all unique solutions
        b    except the first (which is the empty solution)
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 119 chars

```
def S(C,L):
 if L:S(C,L[1:]);S(C+[L[0]],L[1:])
 elif sum(map(int,C))==0and C:print' '.join(C)
S([],raw_input().split())
```

Enumerates all 2^n subsets recursively and checks each one.

Comment: Bravo!  I came within a character...

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 120

I'm a character worse than Keith's solution.  But... this is too close to not post.  One of my favorite features of code-golf is how dissimilar similar-length solutions can be.

```
l=raw_input().split()
print[c for c in[[int(j)for t,j in enumerate(l)if 2**t&i]for i in range(1,2**len(l))]if sum(c)==0]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica <strike>62 57</strike> 38

**Code**

Input entered as integers in an array, `x`.

```
x
```

[image: input]

```
Grid@Select[Subsets@x[[1, 1]], Tr@# == 0 &]
```

---

**Output**

[image: output]

---

**Explanation**

`x[[1, 1]]` converts the input to a list of integers.

`Subsets` generates all subsets from the integers.

`Select....Tr@# == 0` gives all those subsets that have a total equal to 0.

`Grid` formats the selected subsets as space-separated integers.

Answer (score 2):

### Python (<s>128 137</s> 136)

Damn you, `itertools.permutations`, for having such a long name!

Brute force solution. I'm surprised it's not the shortest: but I guess `itertools` ruins the solution.

Ungolfed:

```
import itertools
initial_set=map(int, input().split())
ans=[]
for length in range(1, len(x)+1):
    for subset in itertools.permutations(initial_set, length):
        if sum(subset)==0:
            ans+=str(sorted(subset))
print set(ans)
```

Golfed (ugly output):

```
from itertools import*
x=map(int,input().split())
print set(`sorted(j)`for a in range(1,len(x)+1)for j in permutations(x,a)if sum(j)==0)
```

Golfed (pretty output) (183):

```
from itertools import*
x=map(int,input().split())
print `set(`sorted(j)`[1:-1]for a in range(1,len(x)+1)for j in permutations(x,a)if sum(j)==0)`[5:-2].replace("'","\n").replace(",","")
```

`import itertools as i`: importing the itertools module and calling it `i`

`x=map(int,input().split())`: seperates the input by spaces, then turns the resulting lists' items into integers (`2 3 -5` -> `[2, 3, -5]`)

set(`sorted(j)`for a in range(1,len(x)+1)for j in i.permutations(x,a)if sum(j)==0):
Returns a list of all subsets in `x`, sorted, where the sum is 0, and then gets only the unique items 
(`set(...)`)

The graves (`) around `sorted(j)` is Python shorthand for `repr(sorted(j))`. The reason why this is here is because sets in Python cannot handle lists, so the next best thing is to use strings with a list as the text.

Comment: I'm confused about how you're getting integers instead of strings.  `split()` makes a list of strings, but then later you're calling `sum` on the subsets of that split.

Comment: @KeithRandall: *facepalm* I was in a rush, so I didn't test my code. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: You can probably save a character by doing `from itertools import*`

Comment: actually the graves is shorthand for `repr()`

Comment: @gnibbler: That would make a lot more sense when running \`'hello'\`. Thanks!

Comment: Did you test this?  I get a syntax error on `print \`set(\`...`

Answer (score 2):

## **SWI-Prolog** 84

This version prints the list, instead of trying to find an appropriate binding for a term in a predicate.

```
s([],O):-O=[_|_],sum_list(O,0),print(O).
s([H|T],P):-s(T,[H|P]).
s([_|T],O):-s(T,O).
```

#### Input method

```
s([8,-7,5,-3,-2,4],[]).
```

---

For the record, this is the version that finds a binding to satisfy the predicate:

```
s(L,O):-s(L,0,O),O=[_|_].
s([],0,[]).
s([H|T],S,[H|P]):-R is H+S,s(T,R,P).
s([_|T],S,O):-s(T,S,O).
```

#### Input method

```
s([8,-7,5,-3,-2,4],O).
```

Previous revision contains an incomplete solution that didn't manage to remove empty set.

Answer (score 2):

### C# – 384 characters

OK, functional-style programming in C# is not that *short*, but I *love* it! (Using just a brute-force enumeration, nothing better.)

```cs
using System;using System.Linq;class C{static void Main(){var d=Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(s=>Int32.Parse(s)).ToArray();foreach(var s in Enumerable.Range(1,(1<<d.Length)-1).Select(p=>Enumerable.Range(0,d.Length).Where(i=>(p&1<<i)!=0)).Where(p=>d.Where((x,i)=>p.Contains(i)).Sum()==0).Select(p=>String.Join(" ",p.Select(i=>d[i].ToString()).ToArray())))Console.WriteLine(s);}}
```

Formatted and commented for more readability:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

class C
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // read the data from stdin, split by spaces, and convert to integers, nothing fancy
        var d = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(s => Int32.Parse(s)).ToArray();
        // loop through all solutions generated by the following LINQ expression
        foreach (var s in
            // first, generate all possible subsets; well, first just their numbers
            Enumerable.Range(1, (1 << d.Length) - 1)
            // convert the numbers to the real subsets of the indices in the original data (using the number as a bit mask)
            .Select(p => Enumerable.Range(0, d.Length).Where(i => (p & 1 << i) != 0))
            // and now filter those subsets only to those which sum to zero
            .Where(p => d.Where((x, i) => p.Contains(i)).Sum() == 0)
            // we have the list of solutions here! just convert them to space-delimited strings
            .Select(p => String.Join(" ", p.Select(i => d[i].ToString()).ToArray()))
        )
            // and print them!
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ŒPḊSÐḟ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opICHO7qCD094uGP@////LXR0zXVMdXSNdXSNAA)

Just for completeness. Similar to Brachylog, Jelly also postdates the challenge, but by now, newer languages compete normally.

```
ŒP       Power set.
  Ḋ      Dequeue, remove the first element (empty set).
    Ðḟ   Filter out the subsets with truthy (nonzero)...
   S       sum.
```

Comment: input needs to be space delimited

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
æ¦ʒO>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8LJDy05N8rf7/z/aQkfXXMdUR9dYR9coFgA)

---

If input must be space delimited, prepending `#` to this answer is the only change required.

Answer (score 1):

### J, <strike>57</strike> <strike>53</strike> <strike>51</strike> 49 characters

```
>a:-.~(#:@i.@(2&^)@#<@":@(#~0=+/)@#"1 _])".1!:1[1
```

Usage:

```
   >a:-.~(#:@i.@(2&^)@#<@":@(#~0=+/)@#"1 _])".1!:1[1
8 _7 5 _3 _2 4
5 _3 _2
_7 5 _2 4
8 _7 _3 _2 4
```

Comment: Rewriting the train as `(<@":@(#~0=+/)@#"1 _~2#:@i.@^#)` saves 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)<sup>CP437</sup>

```
â±3╒yΣ╓à
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C3%A2%C2%B13%E2%95%92y%CE%A3%E2%95%93%C3%A0&i=8+-7+5+-3+-2&a=1)

### Explanation

Uses the unpacked version (9 bytes) to explain.

```
LS{|+!fmJ
L            Convert to list
 S           Powerset
  {   f      Filter with block
   |+!       Sum is zero
       mJ    Print each subset, joined by spaces
```

Comment: `Given a list of space-delimited integers as input`; you are -- however -- taking a list as input.

Comment: Will fix at the cost of one byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 34 bytes

```
(a:-.~](<@#~0=+/)@#~[:#:@i.2^#)@".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NRKtdPXqYjVsHJTrDGy19TWBdLSVspVDpp5RnLKmg5Lef02u1OSMfAUNG1OFeGOFeCNNBVuFNAV1C4V4cwWokDpUCZBrag0TtFawADNMwQxzoIiCGZCnqaBrha4fLKH@HwA)

### how

`".` converts the input to a list.  then:

```
a: -.~ ] (<@#~ (0 = +/))@#~ [: #:@i. 2 ^ #
                                  i.       NB. ints from 0 to...
                                     2 ^ # NB. 2 to the input len
                            [: #:@         NB. converted to binary masks
       ] (             ) #~                NB. filter the input using
                                           NB. using those masks, giving
                                           NB. us all subsets
         (             )@                  NB. and to each one...
         (  #~ (0 = +/))                   NB. return it if its sum is
                                           NB. 0, otherwise make it 
                                           NB. the empty list.
         (<@           )                   NB. and box the result.
                                           NB. now we have our answers
                                           NB. and a bunch of empty 
                                           NB. boxes, or aces (a:).
a: -.~                                     NB. remove the aces.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 51 bytes

```perl6
*.words.combinations.skip.grep(!*.sum)>>.Bag.unique
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0uvPL8opVgvOT83KTMvsSQzP69Yrzg7s0AvvSi1QENRS6@4NFfTzk7PKTFdrzQvs7A09b81V3FipUKahpKFgq65gqmCrrGCrpGCiZImXMIYJAYigGL/AQ)

Returns a list of unique Bags that sum to 0. A Bag is a weighted Set.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
*.words                 # Split by whitespace
 .combinations          # Get the powerset
 .skip                  # Skip the empty list
 .grep(!*.sum)          # Select the ones that sum to 0
 >>.Bag                 # Map each to a weighted Set
 .unique                # And get the unique sets
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 110 bytes

```
a=gets.split.map &:to_i;b=[];(1...a.length).each{|c|a.permutation(c){|d|d.sum==0?b<<d:0}};p b.map(&:sort).uniq
```

Will add TIO link later.

Takes input from stdin as a list of numbers, e.g. `8 −7 5 −3 −2`

How it works: It converts the input into an array of numbers. Gets all the permutations of the lengths from 1 to the array's length. It adds them to the output array if they sum to 0. It outputs the array without duplicates.

Output for the sample input: `[[-3, -2, 5]]`