# My array should equal this, but it doesn't!

Tags: code-golf, array

Given an array of integers **`a`** which contains *n* integers, and a single  integer **`x`**; remove the fewest amount of elements from **`a`** to make the sum of **`a`** equal to **`x`**. If no combinations of **`a`** can form **`x`**, return a falsy value.

As pointed out in a comment this is the maximum set with a sum of **x**, excuse my lesser math brain. I forgot a lot of terms since college.

---

**Examples (Truthy):**

`f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 10) = [1,2,3,4]`

`f([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 10) = [2,2,2,2,2]`

`f([2,2,2,2,-2,-2,-2,-4,-2], -8) = [2,2,-2,-2,-2,-4,-2]`

`f([-2,-4,-2], -6) = [-4,-2] OR [-2,-4]`

`f([2,2,2,4,2,-2,-2,-2,-4,-2], 0) = [2,2,2,4,2,-2,-2,-2,-4,-2]` (Unchanged)

`f([], 0) = []` (Unchanged Zero-sum Case)

---

**Examples (Falsy, any consistent non-array value):**

**Impossible to Make Case:** `f([-2,4,6,-8], 3) = falsy (E.G. -1)`

**Zero Sum Case:** `f([], non-zero number) = falsy (E.G. -1)`

- *Note: any value like `[-1]` cannot be valid for falsy, as it is a potential truthy output.*

---

Rules:

- Input may be taken in array form, or as a list of arguments, the last or first being `x`.
- Output may be any delimited list of integers. E.G. `1\n2\n3\n` or `[1,2,3]`.
- Any value can be used as a falsy indicator, other than an array of integers.
- Your code must maximize the size of the end array, order does not matter.

  - E.G. For `f([3,2,3],5)` both `[2,3]` and `[3,2]` are equally valid.
  - E.G. For `f([1,1,2],2)` you can only return `[1,1]` as `[2]` is shorter.
- Both the sum of **`a`** and the value of **`x`** will be less than `2^32-1` and greater than `-2^32-1`.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.
- If there are multiple subarrays of the same size that are valid, it is *not* acceptable to output all of them. You must choose a single one and output that one.

---

Let me know if this has been posted, I couldn't find it.

Posts I found *like this*: [Related but closed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17981/sum-of-numbers-of-array), ...

Comment: I suppose "Falsy, any consistent non-array value" includes raising an error?

Comment: "*Any value can be used as a falsy indicator, other than an array of integers.*" Does that include an empty array?

Comment: @shaggy [] is indicative of a potential truthy value, right? Is allowing that meta rule more important than distinct truthy and falsy?

Comment: @JohnathanAllan if that error cannot be raised in a Truthy scenario- I'd suppose. But I feel this is intentionally attempting to stretch the spec. If i change the wording from indicator to return value is it fine then?

Comment: I do believe consistent exit values do count as a return value though per meta?

Comment: Something like a maybe or option type is pretty important to allow for typed languages that only allow total functions. The general assumption that every type has a falsey value is just bogus.

Comment: @dfeuer falsy and true mean any two distinct values you define. You could output "banana" for true and 293559019 for false if you desire.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
h⊇.+~t?∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P@NRV7uedl2J/aOO5f//R0fHG@nEm@jEG8XqxJvF/o8CAA)

Monthly Brachylog answer. Returns `false.` if it is not possible.

#### Explanation

```
h⊇.           The output is a subset of the head of the input
  .+~t?       The sum of the elements of the output must equal the tail of the input
       ∧      (Avoid implicit unification between the output and the input)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>108</s> 104 bytes

```python
lambda a,n:[x for l in range(len(a)+1)for x in combinations(a,l)if sum(x)==n][-1]
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBaoQwFEX3fsWD2STtE4xjp7bgNxQKXVkXmRntBJIXiSnYr7eR0FHERUkI5N57csPrf/zNUj511eekpTlfJUik13qEzjrQoAicpK@W6ZaY5I@Cz/o46xdrzoqkV5YGJlFz1cHwbdjIq4qaOhVN0jlrQPnWeWv1AMr01vmHqXeKPHSsFpjjEQt8whM@Y4kvKLIGQWQcDhX82U2S3IkcNyvGDxDii7YDpPddhDNQaRlLdswVvgZOsSbe4e0dovuvtmwp2/GBfdDlNs/5ylevLdzmS0WYV1oG@7iJ53z6BQ)

<sub>-4 bytes, thanks to Jonathan Allan</sub>

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>108</s> 106 bytes

```python
def f(a,n):
 q=[a]
 while q:
  x=q.pop(0);q+=[x[:i]+x[i+1:]for i in range(len(x))]
  if sum(x)==n:return x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDBaoQwEIbvPsXAXhIci7p261ryDAuFnkIO0o01sBs1dWn26e2U0FXEQ0kIzPz/N3@Y/j62nc2n6awbaFiNllcRDELWKoLv1lw0DNQAL4anvutZyl@HWEgvK6NiL02cVarpHBgwFlxtPzW7aMs858SDaeDrdqVKCFs5Pd6cBT/1ztiRwmSGOe6xwGc84AuWeMQsVQhZymEn4E9WUfQgclydYN8B2efeBpA8bkEvUUkZQjbEBb4EDiEm1HB6g6D@Ky2dwzZ0YO/2o/1d3pkvps3c6ksF7SspSd6v7DmffgA)

<sub>-2 bytes, thanks to Janathan Frech</sub>

Comment: You could use `range(-len(a),1)` and `-l` to save 2, but [`lambda a,n:[x for l in range(len(a)+1)for x in combinations(a,l)if sum(x)==n][-1]`](https://tio.run/##fVFbbsMgEPzPKVb5ydIuVf2om0Zyj9ALpPkgid0iwWJhLDmndyGW0jSKuqCFGWZGArpT@HZcTG39ORll90cFinizHaF1HgxoBq/4q0HTMCrxmInEj4k/OLvXrIJ23KMiI3QL/WBxFHXNu63MdovWOws6ND44Z3rQtnM@PEwpQhFwSsEFpELMKKeCSnqhil5pTW@UPQuC2M4KQszpZtw/lpdZxh41cn3RXLPVjbO85/2N/wNkklcUkwmKa0k@A7E5L8Gf5k2qzmsOiOniUbiS7yuCdoazqRkPTRf@Nyw/HPTODOnV4xcNfHxaiukH) saves 4.

Comment: Possible [106 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZDBaoQwEIbvPsXAXhIci7p261ryDAuFnkIO0o01sBs1dWn26e2U0FXEQ0kIzPz/N3@Y/j62nc2n6awbaFiNllcRDELWKoLv1lw0DNQAL4anvutZyl@HWEgvK6NiL02cVarpHBgwFlxtPzW7aMs858SDaeDrdqVKCFs5Pd6cBT/1ztiRwmSGOe6xwGc84AuWeMQsVQhZymEn4E9WUfQgclydYN8B2efeBpA8bkEvUUkZQjbEBb4EDiEm1HB6g6D@Ky2dwzZ0YO/2o/1d3pkvps3c6ksF7SspSd6v7DmffgA).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thanks, I must have been tired yesterday ;)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
æʒOQ}0ªéθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LJTk/wDaw0OrTq88tyO//@jDXWMdIx1THRMdcx0zHUsdCx1DA1iuQwNDAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-h`, 11 bytes

```
à f_x ¥VÃñl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AChbT4CoVDS8MONx/emPP/f7SRDgiaALEuHJkAyVgdBQMuLt0MAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

- **8-byter** ([Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=efqz%60sTy&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%5D%0A10&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+9%2C+10%5D%0A10%0A%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%5D%0A10%0A%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-4%2C+-2%5D%0A-8%0A%0A%5B-2%2C+-4%2C+-2%5D%0A-6%0A%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+4%2C+2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-4%2C+-2%5D%0A0%0A%0A%5B%5D%0A0%0A%0A%5B-2%2C+4%2C+6%2C+-8%5D%0A3%0A%0A%5B%5D%0A5%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)) – Outputs only one possible solution. For unsolvable inputs, it doesn't print anything to STDOUT, which is an empty string, which is technically speaking falsey in Pyth, but writes to STDERR. Thanks to [FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman) for suggesting this (ignoring STDERR and focusing on the STDOUT output only), thus saving 1 byte.

  ```
  efqz`sTy
  ```
- **9-byter** ([Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3E1fqz%60sTy&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%5D%0A10&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+9%2C+10%5D%0A10%0A%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%5D%0A10%0A%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-4%2C+-2%5D%0A-8%0A%0A%5B-2%2C+-4%2C+-2%5D%0A-6%0A%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+4%2C+2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-4%2C+-2%5D%0A0%0A%0A%5B%5D%0A0%0A%0A%5B-2%2C+4%2C+6%2C+-8%5D%0A3%0A%0A%5B%5D%0A5%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)) – Outputs only one possible solution, wrapped in a singleton list as [allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884/59487) (e.g. `([1...10], 10) -> [[1,2,3,4]]; ([], 0) -> [[]]`). For unsolvable inputs, it returns `[]`, which is [falsey](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21%21&input=%5B%5D&debug=0) in Pyth.

  ```
  >1fqz`sTy
  ```
- **10-byter** ([Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e%2B0fqz%60sTy&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%5D%0A10&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+9%2C+10%5D%0A10%0A%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%5D%0A10%0A%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-4%2C+-2%5D%0A-8%0A%0A%5B-2%2C+-4%2C+-2%5D%0A-6%0A%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+4%2C+2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-2%2C+-4%2C+-2%5D%0A0%0A%0A%5B%5D%0A0%0A%0A%5B-2%2C+4%2C+6%2C+-8%5D%0A3%0A%0A%5B%5D%0A5%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)) – For a clearer output, without using the singleton-list rule and using `0` rather than `[]` as a falsy value.

  ```
  e+0fqz`sTy
  ```

#### Explanation

First, the code computes the powerset of the input list (all possible ordered sub-collections thereof). Then, it only keeps those collections whose sum is equal to the input number. It should be noted that the collections are generated from the shortest to the longest, so we focus on the last one. To obtain it:

- The **8-byter** simply uses the *end* built-in, which throws an error, but STDERR can be ignored as per our site rules, the output to STDOUT being an empty string, which is falsy.
- The **9-byter** takes the last element, but using the equivalent Python code `lst[-1:]` in place of `lst[-1]` to avoid errors from being thrown for unsolvable inputs.
- The **10-byter** prepends a **0** to the list of filtered sub-collections, then takes the end of that collection (last element). If the inputs aren't solvable, then **0** is naturally used instead.

Comment: `[]` is falsy? Neat. Why does Pyth do that `[]`?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Pyth inherits that from [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) actually: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIyk/P0cjOlZT8/9/AA).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman wouldn't an empty list be a truthy output in the test case `f([], 0) = []`?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks for your suggestion! I've made the necessary changes :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ŒPS⁼¥ƇṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIDgR417Di091v5w56r/h5cfnfRw54z//6ONdCBQF45MgGTsf10LAA)

Output clarified over TIO.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```perl6
{*.combinations.grep(*.sum==$_).tail}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WksvOT83KTMvsSQzP69YL70otUBDS6@4NNfWViVeU68kMTOn9n9xYqVCmoZetGGsJpA0iNVUSMsv4tLQMNQx0jHWMdEx1THTMdex0LHUMTTQ1FEAEUBZIx00iCmlC0cmQBIor2sBlkcWMUPSYYJND8RIOEMXpMxMB2SSgjFMylDzPwA)

Curried function.

Comment: Wait, is the `;` even necessary?

Comment: @JoKing It was necessary in an earlier iteration to avoid a "malformed double closure" error. But for some reason it can be omitted now. (I think after I replaced `$^x` with `$_`.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
⟨⊇+⟩
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahjuVKahlK5fUa5ko4CkC4pV9JUsAWxqh@1bXjU1FwDVpKYU5yqp1T7cFdn7cOtE/4/mr/iUVe79qP5K///j46ONtQx0jHWMdEx1THTMdex0LHUMTSIBePoaCMdNIguEQ9HJkAyVifeAiSLxDdDqDbBoh5sGJSKBykxAxthDBE2MYqNBQA)

Just about equivalent to Fatalize's `h⊇.+~t?∧`, except a **lot** shorter, thanks to the *predicate composition* feature which according to [the edit history of the reference](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki/7)-Predicate-composition/_history) was a work in progress until January 8, postdating the answer by over two months. `⟨⊇+⟩` is a *sandwich*, expanding to `{[I,J]∧I⊇.+J∧}`, where the braces are in this case irrelevant as the sandwich is on its own line anyhow.

```
                The input
[I,J]           is a list of two elements I and J.
        .       The output,
         +J     which sums to J
           ∧    (which we don't unify with the output),
      I⊇        is a sublist of I
     ∧          (which we don't unify with [I,J]).
```

A far less dramatic transformation of Fatalize's answer, which uses the same predicates with the same variables but comes out a byte shorter from being organized differently:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
h⊇.&t~+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahjuVKahlK5fUa5ko4CkC4pV9JUsAWxqh@1bXjU1FwDVpKYU5yqp1T7cFdn7cOtE/5nPOpq11MrqdP@/z86OtpQx0jHWMdEx1THTMdcx0LHUsfQIBaMo6ONdNAgukQ8HJkAyVideAuQLBLfDKHaBIt6sGFQKh6kxAxshDFE2MQoNhYA)

```
           The input
h          's first element
 ⊇         is a superlist of
  .        the output,
   &       and the input
    t      's last item
     ~+    is the sum of the elements of
           the output.
```

(Also, if anyone wants to see something odd, change any of the underscores in the test cases into hyphens.)

Comment: Sandwiches were [implemented by @ais523 in November 2018](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/commit/d9fcabb541297691f53ba8915ea3f17facc8883e) but were only pulled in Brachylog in early January 2019.

Comment: Of course, none of this history-digging matters, since languages that postdate the challenge have been allowed for years.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>100</s> 80 bytes

```r
function(a,x){i[sum(a|1):0,j[combn(a,i,,F),if(sum(j)==x)return(j)]]
F}
`[`=`for`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3BCsIwEETv@QqPu7CFREuRYq/9iVJIDQ2k0ARiAwX122OiKGJBdlmYfcyMj3p3KqIOVi3GWRhoxavpLmGG4Saw5jR1ys3nTAxRi2Q0ZDph06zoxyV4m0Tfs/bOZCcbqZ2XUYOoBSfBkWlQsKefwQ0qPlumi1QcX/zrU/13PANtmEdvFPCtfjcmR0lVLqADxgc)

*20 bytes saved thanks to digEmAll*

Returns `FALSE` for impossible criteria.

Comment: And [80 abusing '[' operator](https://tio.run/##fY3BCsIwEETv@QqPu7CFREuRYq/9iVJIDQ2k0ARiAwX122OiKGJBdlmYfcyMj3p3KqIOVi3GWRhoxavpLmGG4Saw5jR1ys3nTAxRi2Q0ZDph06zoxyV4m0Tfs/bOZCcbqZ2XUYOoBSfBkWlQsKefwQ0qPlumi1QcX/zrU/13PANtmEdvFPCtfjcmR0lVLqADxgc "R – Try It Online") :D

Comment: @digEmAll I'm certainly glad I didn't get a chance to edit in your 98 byte answer :-)

Comment: eheh forgot to delete it :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
A.Q|>1fqsTHyG0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31EvsMbOMK2wOMSj0t3g//9oQx0jHWMdEx1THbNYLkMDAA)

Answer (score 2):

This started out cool and small, but edge cases got me. Whatever happens, I'm proud of the work I put into this.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>169 161</s> 154 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
def f(a,x):
	if sum(a)==x:return a
	try:return[c for i in range(len(a))for c in combinations(a,i)if sum(c)==x][-1]
	except:return 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDdisMgEIWv41MM9EaXCeRvu9lCnqFQ2KuQC9dqKzQajIX06bOGptsQgiLMmfnOkeke/mpNPo7K2Ra0l85be@tBt511/oOcpQJFOQ7sQCKtoL@3lLOqGg5O@rszwEnk3WOuagHKOtCgDThuLpLepAnzbFLFpArb/mrDvbamD7aazZ5i8mzqOG1IJAchO/8KSMbOaeOBKlqnmGGOBX7iHr@wxG9MkwYhTRiDXQWvfkPIm8lwdWZgBwF4i1tI/H@L8AYuLuegje7SYIns56inAMcTPNsbicVWZrKI3BwB@mPEddr2mS09F@z6c0XYX1yGgZytkYyx8Q8)

Comment: Remember that this is [code-golf] so you should try to make your byte count as small as possible! You have a leading newline and some other [trivial whitespace golfs](https://tio.run/##bZDNaoQwFIXX5ikuzCYpV/CvUzuQZygUuhIXqZN0AmMiMQPO09uItopIQhbn3O@ccLunv1mTj6NytgXtpfPW3nvQbWedfyFXqUBRgQO7kEgrEJxXtTBXGDhPLk76hzOUkci7ZxiIZqFqQFkHGrQBJ8yPpHdpqGBsUptJbWz7rY3w2po@pGsWovtHSxvG@VBXcVqTSA6N7PyaCsnYOW08UEWrFDPMscBXPOMblviOaVIjpAljcOLw59eErEyGu7MAJwjAKh4h8f8twhu4uFyKDtxtwBY5L1WzAB@fMNsHjcVRZ7KpPBwB@mWa27TwK9tmbtj954qwv7gMAznbIxlj4y8), and I bet someone else who knows python can golf this down further.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks for reminding me of the leading whitespace. I spent some time trying to consolidate some parts of this, but decided to post it in the meantime in case any others can suggest edits.

Comment: Not a problem! It's been like 5 years since I did any Python, but doesn't `range(x)` generate `(0...x-1)`? So your `range(len(a))` isn't giving you the possibility of leaving the array unchanged?

Comment: @Giuseppe Eureka, that did it. I may have been focusing too much on the new material I was working with.

Comment: Instead of `if a==[] and x==0` use `if sum(a)==x`. Then you can also remove `+1` from `range`.

Comment: @VedantKandoi That handles the zero-sum and whole-length cases at once, thanks!

Comment: You could have false be returned as the presence of an error, the if else can be a list, and then you can turn it into a lambda. [117 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZHdasQgEIXv8xQDe6NlAvnrNi3kGQqFXlkvXDd2hajBWNg@fZp0064EUbw4Z745o47f4eJsPSvo4GMehDmdBQi8vjAmQTkPGrQFL@xnT4beEkHpqspVlc6ctBVBOzsRgZpqBdOXIZJ23ZWzvOQoOFsV8atkyjsDOvQ@ODdMoM3ofHiYR69tAKIIK7HCGht8xCM@YYvPWBYcoSwohUMHfz7PsjtT4W5twGG50d1MIvn/bpZz4fJ2C0q4cYMYOW5RNwFe3@BmJxKbVGYRRSZLgLxbeVl/4EzjnhG7H65Z3i9vl4Ka7pGK0vkH "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing Is the implementation supposed to crash on a falsey case?

Comment: Yes? [This is confirmed by the asker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175027/my-array-should-equal-this-but-it-doesnt/175047?noredirect=1#comment421868_175027), but I'm pretty sure presence of an error is valid output from default IO

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 89 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Data.List,Data.Func
$n=find((==)n o sum)o sortBy(on(>)length)o subsequences
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PUyxCsIwFNz9ijd0SKF1EAeXOEgVhA5CR3F4pmkNJC/avAj9eWOkIHccdwd3ymqk5HwfrQaHhpJxTz8xdNwf6V01yLhuTeDFnSKpVUFyMNQLIWVJ4CFEV2bNq8MsPIl9aTWN/PiV8R70K2pSOqSOMR9LKKDewXVTLaj/3Ga9pY8aLI4h1ec2NTOhM2oJF4s8@Ml9AQ)

Defines the function `$ :: Int -> [Int] -> (Maybe [Int])` returning `Nothing` if there is no appropriate combination of elements, and `(Just [elements...])` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 108 bytes

Takes input as `(array)(n)`. Returns either an array or `false`.

```javascript
a=>n=>a.reduce((a,x)=>[...a,...a.map(y=>1/r[(y=[...y]).push(x)]||eval(y.join`+`)-n?y:r=y)],[[]],r=!n&&[])&&r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHfaoMwFMbv@xTZjSTsGGvrOjeIu9gDDAa7mQQaNPYPNpFklgp9d6dra0V0JyG5OOf35fvIXhyFTcyu@HGVTmWdsVqwSLFIUCPTMpEYCzgRFsWUUgHtQQ@iwBWLfM/Ezd02Kk5oUdotPhF@PsujyHFF93qn1o9r4qq36tWwinCIY87BsAflODEnjmPqRCurc0lzvcEZjn1YwBICeIIVPEMIL@DPOcH@nBDUlOeh2wifDdAFDFaPu6L31hTsdjtozkbBDVuFGzxoD1X63Kp7uatW5dJHH5/oMj3hJBjz0oa5xxgZQfhLJVuhNjIlQ90rP1Wtbp9H39Jo15YH9C6sJLORqEHzR27Y6C5Ho2Yit3LExfJ/F39Y/Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 28 bytes

```
${(y&`=@Sum\Radiations@x)@0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBlq/BfpVqjUi3B1iG4NDcmKDElM7EkMz@v2KFC08Gg9r9fampKcbRKQUFyeixXQFFmXklIanGJc2JxanF0moODZ4qOQjSXAhBERxvqGOkY65jomOqY6ZjrWOhY6hgaxOoogAioCiMdNIhdWheOTIAkUI2uBVwNsqgZmk4TbHoRxqNwdEHKzXRAJisYIysxMYrlio39DwA)

### Alternatives

**34 bytes**: `f[x,y]:=({y=Sum@_}\Radiations@x)@0`

**30 bytes**: `` First@${y&`=@Sum\Radiations@x} ``

**29 bytes**: `` {(_&`=@Sum\_2)@0}#/Radiations ``

**29 bytes**: `${({y=Sum@_}\Radiations@x)@0}`

**29 bytes**: `` `@&0@${y&`=@Sum\Radiations@x} ``

**29 bytes**: `` {_}@@${y&`=@Sum\Radiations@x} ``

### Explanation

```
${(y&`=@Sum\Radiations@x)@0}
${                         }    function receiving two arguments, x and y
            Radiations@x        calculate the radiations of x
                                (simulates removing all possible subslices of x)
           \                    keep those radiations
        Sum                     ...whose sum...
     `=@                        ...equals...
   y&                           ...y
  (                     )@0     select the first one (always the longest)
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 65 chars, 130 bytes

```
{m←⍺=+/¨v←1↓{0=⍴⍵:⊂⍬⋄s,(⊂1⌷⍵),¨s←∇1↓⍵}⍵⋄0=↑⍴b←m/v:⍬⋄b⊃⍨n⍳⌈/n←⍴¨b}
```

↓ is used because the first element of the set of sets would be one void set (here ⍬ Zilde),
that one want eliminate because it seems +/⍬ is zero...

For not find, or error it would return ⍬ or in print text:

```
  o←⎕fmt
  o ⍬
┌0─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
```

test:

```
  z←{m←⍺=+/¨v←1↓{0=⍴⍵:⊂⍬⋄s,(⊂1⌷⍵),¨s←∇1↓⍵}⍵⋄0=↑⍴b←m/v:⍬⋄b⊃⍨n⍳⌈/n←⍴¨b}

  o 1 z ,1
┌1─┐
│ 1│
└~─┘
  o 2 z ,1
┌0─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
  o 10 z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
┌4───────┐
│ 1 2 3 4│
└~───────┘
  o 10 z 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
┌5─────────┐
│ 2 2 2 2 2│
└~─────────┘
  o ¯8 z 2,2,2,2,¯2,¯2,¯2,¯4,¯2
┌7──────────────────┐
│ 2 2 ¯2 ¯2 ¯2 ¯4 ¯2│
└~──────────────────┘
  o ¯6 z ¯2,¯4,¯2
┌2─────┐
│ ¯4 ¯2│
└~─────┘
  o 0 z 2,2,2,4,2,¯2,¯2,¯2,¯4,¯2
┌10───────────────────────┐
│ 2 2 2 4 2 ¯2 ¯2 ¯2 ¯4 ¯2│
└~────────────────────────┘
  o 10 z 1 2 3 4
┌4───────┐
│ 1 2 3 4│
└~───────┘
  o 10 z 1 2 3
┌0─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
  o 0 z ⍬
┌0─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
  o +/⍬  
0
~
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
▲fo=⁰ΣQ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9odXNr///ilrJmbz3igbDOo1HCsv///1stMiwtNCwtMl3/LTY)

Brachylog is **insane.**

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 68 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f x=find((==x).sum).sortOn(sum.(-1<$)).subsequences
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzNCoMwEITvPsUePETYiPGntdDceiz0AaSHVJM2VKM1EXz6pimFgswyLDMf8xD2Kfveez1M4@zgJJxIz9q6SMHKlTYdIZyvSWqXIVhALoaEPyWUHePkm9@sfC3StNL6QWgDHLoxAphmbRzEoIBl0DDMscASK9zhHms8IMuuG4rQOoEmx5/o/8rgWzLMbYMCmkCWYZrW26YKqH@3qhd362k7TR8)

Defines `f x a` to return `Just` a subset or `Nothing`.

The only trick here is that `sum.(-1<$)` is one  byte shorter than `(0-).length`.