# Zero sum in python 2.7

Tags: python, c

Write a function in Python 2.7 that takes a list of integers as an argument. It should return True or False depending on whether there are any 2 integers in the argument list that sum to zero.
[4,-4,9,6,5]

> > True

[6,5,-3,2]

> > False

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! That's a nice challenge, but unfortunately, we don't like challenges that allow only one language. This challenge is also missing a [winning criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/908/72792). I'd recommend you to look at few other of challenges there and use our [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges#show-editor-button) next time.

Comment: I'm guessing this must be code golf as I can't see any other reasonable criteria. (I added the code golf tag, but if that is wrong feel free to specify the correct winning criteria  and remove it.)

Comment: @Arlene what should we return for `[0]`?

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8655/45941)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Please [stop editing programming questions to make them on-topic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14838). Either OP edit the winning criteria in themselves or we close (and optionally someone else repost) it.

Comment: @user202729 I didn't think there was any harm, meta read and noted - it makes sense; thanks

Comment: I think the challenge is too easy

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
lambda a:any(-n in a for n in a)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHRKjGvUkM3TyEzTyFRIS2/SAHC1PwPYpekFpeAuBrRJjq6JjqWOmY6prE6CtFASkfXWMcoVtOKSwEICooy80o0QKp1FNR17dR1FNLAPE3N/wA)**

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 23 bytes

```r
function(x)any(-x%in%x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQjMxr1JDt0I1M0@1QvN/mkayhqGCjpGCjomCjqmCjpmCjiWYNAWLmCvo6Jppav4HAA)

If full programs are allowed:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 21 bytes

```r
any((x=scan())%in%-x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzGvUkOjwrY4OTFPQ1NTNTNPVbdC87@hgpGCiYKpgpmCJRCbAtnmCrpm/wE)

Comment: Yes any language is fine. Sorry I am new to this. Thank you!

Comment: @Arlene Thank you and welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @Arlene Please edit your question to reflect the fact that all languages are allowed. Also if you are interested in the shortest solution, I suggest you tag your question [tag:code-golf]